# SimpleDrillDown example with TabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.3

I have been experimenting with the SimpleDrillDown example from Apple and attempted to put it into a tab bar. The problem is the view now doesn't show, and I know it is the following code in the App Delegate that is causing it. I am struggling with changing it to fit with the tabbar and would appreciate some pointers.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

  // Create the data controller and pass it to the root view controller.
  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];

  DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.dataController = controller;
  self.dataController = controller;
}
```

I have replaced it with the following but this line `EatCatTVC *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];` throws an error

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  // Create the data controller and pass it to the root view controller.

  EatCatTVC *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
  DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.dataController = controller;
  self.dataController = controller;
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: You're missing `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Comment: That's not in the original sample code anywhere which works fine

Comment: You are asking `navigationController` for a controller but it isn't present anymore in your updated version.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing because you are accessing non-existent object

```
EatCatTVC *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
```

on this line `navigationController` doesn't exist in your "modified" version.

Make sure that "rootController" is set to `UITabBarController` class (I assume that you did setup this in Interface Builder).

And then use `setViewControllers:animated:` to provide the `UITabBarController' instance with (for instance)`UIViewController` instances that are meant to be present.

Comment: Thanks. I set it up with storyboard so it just "worked" with table views and NSArrays, however the simpledrilldown is exactly what my app requires. The 1st tab is a detail view, the second is the tableview but the data just doesn't load. The rootController is a tabbarcontroller in storyboard, and is set to UITabBarController. I'll try the setView.

Comment: No good - I just can't seem to get it to work and I have totally confused myself with code now, but thanks for trying to help

Comment: I have the following code sort of working but with an error "No visible @interface for EatCatTVC declares the selector 'viewcontrollers' 
`(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
UITabBarController *tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController;
EatCatTVC *EatCatTVCnav = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
EatCatTVC *eatCatTVC = [[EatCatTVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];
    eatCatTVC.dataController = controller;
    self.dataController = controller;
 
      }`

Comment: that usually means, that you either forgot to `import` the header file of a class your are using or didn't declare such property

Comment: thats what I thought too but its all there. I am going to try a different approach until I am more familiar with objective C.